# Password validation (2 Textboxes, comparision)

Tags: javascript, html

before you blame me, yes I was looking for something similar for about a hour, but sadly I couldn't find my error, atleast the Questions I was looking for in stackoverflow didn't gave me a correct answere, as I have almost exactly the same thing (not Copy and Paste).
However could someone explain me, why my code (javascript) isn't working?
I am playing around with it for some hours now but I can't find it.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Anmeldung/Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

    <script>
        function abc(){
        var a = document.getElementById('pw').value;
        var b = document.getElementById('repw').value;

        if(a==b){
            alert(yes)
        }
        }
    </script>


</head>     
    <body>

        <div id="banner">
                <p>NAME/ÜBERSCHRIFT</p>
        </div>

        <form id="loginpanel">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>LOGIN</legend>
                <p class="textinput">Benutzername: <input name="id" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"></p>
                <p class="textinput">Passwort: <input name="pw" type="password" size="30" maxlength="15"></p>
                <input class="button" type="button" name="login" value="Anmelden"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <p id="option"> ...oder Registrieren!</p>

        <form id="registerpanel">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>REGISTER</legend> 
                <p class="textinput">Benutzername: <input name="id" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"></p>
                <p class="textinput">eMail: <input name="email" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"></p>
                <p class="textinput">Passwort: <input name="pw" type="password" size="30" maxlength="30"></p>
                <p class="textinput">Passwort wiederholen: <input name="repw" type="password" size="30" maxlength="30"></p>           
                <input class="button" type="button" onclick="abc()" name="register" value="Registrieren"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
```

I would be happy if someone can give me an answere!
Thank you for taking your time :)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have inputs with `id` attribute with values `pw`+`repw`. Having only a `name` attribute will not work

example: `<input name="repw" id="repw" type="password" size="30" maxlength="30">`

Corrected version (only relevant parts):

```
<script>
window.abc = function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('pw').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('repw').value;

    if(a==b){
        alert("yes")
    }
}
</script>
...
<form id="registerpanel">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>REGISTER</legend> 
                <p class="textinput">Benutzername: <input name="id" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"></p>
                <p class="textinput">eMail: <input name="email" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"></p>
                <p class="textinput">Passwort: <input name="pw" id="register-pw" type="password" size="30" maxlength="30"></p>
                <p class="textinput">Passwort wiederholen: <input name="repw" id="register-repw" type="password" size="30" maxlength="30"></p>           
                <input class="button" type="button" onclick="abc()" name="register" value="Registrieren"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Note the added IDs. I didn't do `pw` and `repw` because having plain `pw` in login made more sense to me (11684) (don't forget to add that in the login form). Because I'd do `register-pw` I went for consistency and did `register-repw`. But it doesn't matter what these IDs are *as long as they are unique*.
And I changed the typo `alert(yes)` into `alert("yes")` because obviously the first throws a reference error.

A working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7NZUc/

Comment: Also, there isn't even an element with the name "repw"!

Comment: Yea I know, I've tried it before but it didn't work. Now I tried it once again and it still isn't working.

Comment: There is. Look at the `registerpanel`. @Ian

Comment: @11684 Oh jeez, I didn't even scroll down to see all that. You're right, nevermind!

Comment: I do agree with your answer, do you mind if I edit a corrected version of the OP's code in? That is kind of a major edit, so I thought I'd ask. (@Alon)

Comment: Thank you guys, worked now, 1 more Question though, why "window.abc = function()"? Why not function abc()?